# How to draw curved lines continuously in core graphics ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, core-graphics

In an iOS application, I want to draw continuously curved lines like shown in below image. Here is my code but it draws only single straight line.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    
    // set the line properties
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 30);
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, 0.6);
    
    // draw the line
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

---

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint current = [touch locationInView:self];
    startPoint=current;
    arrPoints=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [arrPoints addObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(startPoint)];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];

    endPoint=p;
    [arrPoints addObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(endPoint)];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Here is the image what I want to achieve is suppose there are five view and I want to draw continues line starting from first view to second,third,etc... and at same time I want to draw curve at each view in line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is already building an array of points.

Now you need to modify your drawRect method to draw line segments between all the points, not just the latest one.

You will probably get better performance if you build a `UIBezierPath` out of your line segments and draw that in one go.

The result of this will be a continuous series of short line segments that approximate a curve. If the user moves his finger quickly then the line segments will be longer, making the curve look more choppy.

Once you get that working there are techniques you can use to smooth the resulting curve. Erica Sadun's excellent "Core iOS Developer's cookbook" has a recipe called "Smoothing" covering this very topic. It does exactly what you want - takes a freehand drawing by the user and smooths it.

I have a couple of projects on Github that use Erica Sadun's line smoothing technique.

The project [**KeyframeViewAnimations**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/KeyframeViewAnimations) draws a curve that passes through a set of predefined points.

The project "[**RandomBlobs**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/RandomBlobs)" draws a closed curve which is a smoothed version of a polygon.

Both of these include Dr. Sadun's curve-smoothing code, but again, the chapter from her book is the best fit for your needs.

Comment: what i want to achieve is suppose there are five view and i started drawing from one view and move line to another view at second view i want to draw curve in which direction finger moves

Comment: Based on your description the smoothing technique outlined in Erica Sadun's "Core iOS Developer's cookbook" in the recipe "Smoothing drawings" is exactly what you want. It uses a technique called Catmull-Rom splines to create a smooth curve from the points of a user drawing with his finger. I suggest buying that book. It's chock-full of gems like that one, and that one "recipe" is worth the price of the book since it does exactly what you want.